# Use Ubuntu Server as Proxy

Tags: networking, server, proxy, dns

First of all if i'm asking this question at wrong place i'm terribly sorry for it. I'm an expert about NT Servers but very rookie about linux systems, i'm making tests to learn it. I want to share internet connection via Ubuntu Server but i don't want to enter proxy address from IE or Chrome to user's computers manually. Maybe some of you know devices like Sonicwall etc. those devices provides ip address, gateway and dns to computers so you don't need to enter manually. I found many articles about squid & dhcp installation and configuration but almost in every article people says you need to enter proxy settings manually. I was wondering can you guys offer me an article or document how i can do that. As i said before i google it so many articles and they give you the commands and parameters but almost none of it explaining why we using that command, i mean what does it means or what does it do. If somebody can share an article or document or link for a rookie as me it will be great.

Thanks for understanding and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi There!! What is your main motive on running proxy service on an Ubuntu. Is it to block or take control of the internet within the LAN?? or just offer internet only??

Comment: @AzkerM actually both of it, i can do it with ISA server on NT server, but we all know linux is much more stable fast and source friendly, that's why i want to learn and become an expert about linux servers too. In this case i'm sure i can do same thing with linux what i can do with ISA. I want to share internet and block websites and get report which user visiting which web site etc.

Comment: Well yes you can achieve this with the combination of `squid + squidguard` for proxy. But as an alternative you can try [**pfsense**](https://pfsense.org) out the box. I'm using **pfsense** with **WPAD** which helps the users not fill proxy manual filling part. I hope I can complete that article sooner. :/

Comment: @AzkerM pfsense looks really professional, i'll search articles for it and please try to prepare an article for it :) It's always good to get explanations & help from friends.

Comment: I've drafted some articles about proxy & configuring it with LDAP authentication. So that you can see who's visiting where using `sarg`. Moreover there are plenty of fruitful features you'll see while you browse. :)

Comment: @AzkerM yes there is really good articles about proxy,firewall applications with ubuntu, i printed out some of it, i'll work on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated "share internet connection" in your post, but I get the sense (from your mention of Sonicwall) that what you actually want is to have a highly configurable device on your network for monitoring traffic, traffic shaping or QoS, and blocking certain sites or services.

If you want it to be transparent and not have to change any settings on the user's PCs, you would probably have to set up an [Ubuntu server as the default gateway](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926001) on your network. Right now you probably have a router of some sort that connects your internal network with the outside world. You would basically be setting up an Ubuntu machine to replace your router.

It is possible to set up an Ubuntu server to do what you want without making it the default gateway on the network, but the problem is those aren't as transparent. You'll need to change settings on the user's computers to point to this box. The downside to setting up an Ubuntu gateway is that it's a fairly tall order for a Linux newcomer. The upside is Ubuntu is typically documented very well and you will get a huge amount of flexibility in how you configure, block, QoS, and monitor traffic.

Comment: you are right, i want to use ubuntu server as default gateway and block or allow some web sites or services, i'll read the link you provide, as a newcomer you are definetly right it won't be so easy for me, but i'll work hard and learn :) As you said Ubuntu is very well documented about everything, for now i'm doing tests on virtual machines and virtual networks. Of course there will be some changes on user's machines even for NT servers you need to do it, i'll also check articles about transparent proxy on ubuntu.